# How to subset rows for a specific range of dates in r?

Tags: r, date

I am new to R and currently working on some rainfall data. I have two data frames named df1 and df2.

```
 df1

 Date   Duration_sum
 5/28/2014  110
 5/31/2014  20
 5/31/2014  20
 6/1/2014   10
 6/1/2014   110
 6/3/2014   140
 6/4/2014   40
 6/5/2014   60
 6/12/2014  10
 6/14/2014  100

 df2

 Date   PercentRemoval
 6/2/2014   25.8
 6/5/2014   78.58
 6/6/2014   15.6
 6/13/2014  70.06
```

I want to look up the dates from df2 in df1. For example, if the 1st date from df2 is available in df1, I want to subset rows in df1 within the range of that specific date and 3 days prior to that. If that date is not available, then just look for the previous 3 days.

In case the data for previous 3 days are not available, then it will extract as many days as available but maximum limit is 3 days prior to the specific date of df2. If none of the dates are available in df1, then that date is ignored and look for the next date in df2. Also, for example, 3 days prior to 6/6/2014 is available in df1 but we have already  considered those days for 6/5/2014. So, 6/6/2014 is ignored.

The resulted data frame should look something like this:

```
df3

  col_1         Date        Duration_sum
             5/31/2014         20
             5/31/2014         20
             6/1/2014          10
6/2/2014     6/1/2014         110
             6/3/2014         140
             6/4/2014          40
6/5/2014     6/5/2014          60
6/13/2014    6/12/2014         10
```

I have used this code:

```
df3 <- df1[df1$Date %in% as.Date(c(df2)),]
```

this code gives me the results for specific dates but not for the previous 3 days. I would really appreciate If someone can help me out with this code or some other codes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be one way to do the task. If I am correctly reading your question, you want to remove any date, which does not have more than 3 days as an interval with a previous date. In this way, you can avoid the overlapping issue you mentioned in your question; you can successfully remove the 5th of June, 2014. Once you filter dates in `df2`, you can subset `df1` for each date in the revised `df2` in the `lapply()` part. The output is a list, and you want to assign names to each data frame in the list. Finally, you bind all data frames.

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(df1, Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) -> df1

mutate(df2, Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
filter(!(Date - lag(Date, default = 0) < 3)) -> df2

lapply(df2$Date, function(x){
    filter(df1, between(Date, x-3, x)) -> foo
    foo
}) -> temp

names(temp) <- as.character(df2$Date)
bind_rows(temp, .id = "df2.date")

#    df2.date       Date Duration_sum
#1 2014-06-02 2014-05-31           20
#2 2014-06-02 2014-05-31           20
#3 2014-06-02 2014-06-01           10
#4 2014-06-02 2014-06-01          110
#5 2014-06-05 2014-06-03          140
#6 2014-06-05 2014-06-04           40
#7 2014-06-05 2014-06-05           60
#8 2014-06-13 2014-06-12           10
```

DATA

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("5/28/2014", "5/31/2014", "5/31/2014", 
"6/1/2014", "6/1/2014", "6/3/2014", "6/4/2014", "6/5/2014", "6/12/2014", 
"6/14/2014"), Duration_sum = c(110L, 20L, 20L, 10L, 110L, 140L, 
40L, 60L, 10L, 100L)), .Names = c("Date", "Duration_sum"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

df2 <- structure(list(Date = c("6/2/2014", "6/5/2014", "6/6/2014", "6/13/2014"
), PercentRemoval = c(25.8, 78.58, 15.6, 70.06)), .Names = c("Date", 
"PercentRemoval"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: @Sami  Pleasure to help you. :)

Comment: I badly need your help again. What happens if I want to solve the same problem mentioned here, but in this case I do not want to remove any date from df2, which does not have more than 3 days as an interval with a previous date in df1. For example, in df2, for 6/6/2014, there is date available within 3 days range in df1. So, in this case I just want to extract the same value as it's previous date (6/5/2014) had in df2.

Comment: Or in other words, for a specific date of df2, if there are no dates available within 3 days interval, i want the code to keep on looking beyond 3 days and extract whenever a date is available. I would really appreciate your help.